# Assertion of String values is not working correctly

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to assert the table headers of a table (found here - "http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/") using Cucumber.

The comparison is happening, and should be equal, but for some reason my assertion is failing.

I will list the error, the code and the feature file -

Error -

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<[Structure]> but was:<Structure>
```

Code -

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Then("^table with id \"([^\"]*)\" has header values of$")
public void tableHeaders(String id, DataTable table) {

    java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> expectedHeaders = table.raw();

    WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    List<WebElement> allHeaders = container.findElements(By.tagName("th"));

    List<String> actualHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement header : allHeaders) {
        actualHeaders.add(header.getText().toString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < actualHeaders.size(); i++) {
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedHeaders.get(i), actualHeaders.get(i));
    }
}
```

Feature File-

```
Scenario: Test Table Header assertion 
Then table with id "content" has header values of 

    | Structure |
    | Country | 
    | City |
    | Height | 
    | Built | 
    | Rank |
    | ... |
```

Comment: Call toString on the actual value. You’re comparing a string to something that isn’t a string.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I think both are already set to strings: 
    List<String>> expectedTitles = table.raw(); 
    stringOfHeaders.add(header.getText().toString());

Answer (score 2):

Like @nathan-hughes already said: you're comparing a list of Strings with a String. `expectedTitles` is a list of lists of Strings and `stringOfHeaders` is only a list of Strings. Therefore

```
assertEquals(expectedTitles.get(i), stringOfHeaders.get(i))
```

is comparing a list of Strings with a String and fails because of that. I think what you would like to do is

```
assertEquals(expectedTitles.get(i).get(0), stringOfHeaders.get(i))
```

Comment: Yes Stefan, you were right, your suggestion helped, thank you! One thing, after the comparison finishes successfully, I get the following error - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7 Maybe my loop is not correct?